# How to get specific item from Array Collection in Adobe Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

In this specific part of code:

```
<s:DataGroup
  dataProvider="{prodCollection}" 
  itemRenderer="spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer">

  <s:layout>
    <s:HorizontalLayout />
  </s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

the `ArrayCollection` is built from a XML file but `prodCollection` (bindable) is formed by many childrens. In fact this code returns `[obj][obj]` and I would like to extract one: `product_name`.

I tried without result to:

- use a *for* loop by function : `prodCollection.getItemAt(i).product_name`
- use `idHttpservice.LastResult.Lista.product_name in dataprovider="{}"`

The part of XML file:

```
<lista>
  <Prodotto>
    <fam>Soft Drink</fam>
    <product_name>Coca Cola</product_name>
    <image>images/coca_cola.gif</image>
  </Prodotto>
</lista>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a custom item renderer instead of DefaultItemRenderer, and define it in a separate file like this:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns="...">

    <s:Label text="{ data.product_name }"/>
    ...
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Thanks it works now . Please  can you tell me why in the separate Component the prop "data" works? Thanks.

Comment: `data` is a property of ItemRenderer class, it contains a single item from the data provider. you can pass any type of data and render it the way you want in your custom item renderer.

Comment: Thanks, but  if I creata a  new custom component  I'm able to use data prop .. why? It isn't just for a itemRenderer  .. it seams is for all custom components . Is like to  create a super class ? Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: well, I don't think that all Flex classes has `data` property... you can check the Adobe's Flex reference to see where the particular property comes from (and is it inherited or not). also, please accept my answer if it worked.